# how to indexing table in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem in indexing with ng-repeat

```
   <tr ng-repeat="Ward in Wardresult ">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
         ......................
            some column
        .......................
     </tr>
```

but in output
result in index is

Sr
     1
     10
     11
     12
     13
     .
     .
     .
     2
     3
     4

how can i solve this problem i use ng-init and also i take index in JS ,convert into int but result is in same format.

Comment: <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="Ward in Wardresult">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
it works ,please post your full code

Comment: post more code, because it works in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1dhwt2q/)

Answer (score 1):

Please Use track by $index

Code :

```
<div ng-repeat="Ward in Wardresult track by $index" >
      {{$index + 1}}
    </div>
```

Working [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2GCgCVsyvYx70QTXgedz?p=preview)

Comment: i did this , but stil result is in 1,10,11,12, ... format

Comment: actually i am taking data from database and store in Wardresult .

Comment: i tried all the posible ways to solve this problem but i think there is some problem with ng-repeat .It take all valueas as string.